# Trying to build an html toutuorial and can't get my javascript to check the value for my textbox to get checked by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, if-statement

Hi Im trying to get my code to work for checking if the html is right in the textarea. If it is right it will open another page with what was in the textarea already as a website (this part works I checked before creating the if else). I only want that to happen if the code in the textarea is the same as what I put in my value in javascript (this dosent work). Heres my whole html for that page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Lesson 1</title>
                        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowResult()
        {
            var check = x ;
            var html = "<h1>This is Heading 1</h1><h2>This is Heading 2</h2><h3>This is Heading 3</h3><h4>This is Heading 4</h4><h5>This is Heading 5</h5><h6>This is Heading 6</h6><p>This is Paragraph Text</p><blockquote><p>This is in a qoute</p><small>Person <cite>Source Title</cite></small></blockquote>" ;
            if (check === html) {
                my_window = window.open("about:blank", "mywindow1");
                my_window.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Lesson 1 Result</title><link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body>' + '<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-info"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><strong>Tip</strong> This is your code editor output. It will sow up when you are right in your lesson. To go back and continue close this tab ( click the x on the top bar of your web browser )</p></div><p>' + x + '</body></html>');
            }
        }       
    </script>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Learn Lesson 1 HTML Syntax</div>
                <div class="panel-body">

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Ad starts here-->
        <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- LRN Ad -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:100px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-9273905782779277"
     data-ad-slot="9421350343"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
        <!-- ends here -->
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <textarea style="font-size:15px; resize: none; height: 600px; width: 100%; font-family: Consolas,monaco,monospace; background-color: #6F6F6F; color: #F9F9F9;" onblur="x=this.value">
<h1>This is Heading 1</h1>
<h2>This is Heading 2</h2>
<h3>This is Heading 3</h3>
<h4>This is Heading 4</h4>
<h5>This is Heading 5</h5>
<h6>This is Heading 6</h6>
<p>This is Paragraph Text</p>
<blockquote>
  <p>This is in a qoute</p>
  <small>Person <cite>Source Title</cite></small>
</blockquote>

        </textarea>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <br />
            <a onclick="ShowResult()" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Try it out</a>
            <!-- Ad starts here-->
        <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- LRN Ad -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:100px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-9273905782779277"
     data-ad-slot="9421350343"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
        <!-- ends here -->

            <hr>
            <br/>
            <p>Copyleft ;-) Maksim Tonyushkin 2015</p>
        </div>

        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The part that doesn't work is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowResult()
        {
            var check = x ;
            var html = "<h1>This is Heading 1</h1><h2>This is Heading 2</h2><h3>This is Heading 3</h3><h4>This is Heading 4</h4><h5>This is Heading 5</h5><h6>This is Heading 6</h6><p>This is Paragraph Text</p><blockquote><p>This is in a qoute</p><small>Person <cite>Source Title</cite></small></blockquote>" ;
            if (check === html) {
                my_window = window.open("about:blank", "mywindow1");
                my_window.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Lesson 1 Result</title><link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body>' + '<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-info"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><strong>Tip</strong> This is your code editor output. It will sow up when you are right in your lesson. To go back and continue close this tab ( click the x on the top bar of your web browser )</p></div><p>' + x + '</body></html>');
            }
        }
    </script>
```

The value x is given on the textarea onblur="x=this.value". 
Any help?

Comment: the textarea value does not contain the HTMl tags.

Comment: I am not sure that your x variable gets the needed value.
you might want to try "this.innerHTML"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by like dis (the reason it wasn't working was because of the spacing):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Lesson 0</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico">
                        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowResult()
        {
            var x = document.getElementById("html").value
            var z = document.getElementById("answer").value
            if (x === z) {
                my_window = window.open("about:blank", "mywindow1");
                my_window.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Lesson 0 Result</title><link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body>' + '<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-info"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><strong>Tip</strong> This is your code editor output. It will show up when you are right. To go back and continue close this tab ( click the x on the top bar of your web browser )</p></div><p>' + x + '</body></html>');
            }
        }   
    </script>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Learn Lesson 0 Geting started</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    The first lesson will be a tutorial on how to use this website.  This part of the webpage is the part that teaches about code and gives you examples. Below is what you will need to do to complete this lesson.  The gray box is your code editor. Inside it you will write your code for the lesson. Good luck on your first lesson (click answers if you need help).
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Steps</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Answer</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="home">

                <div class="list-group">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">1.</h4>
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Click on the code editor and between the <code>&lt;h1&gt;</code> and <code>&lt;/h1&gt;</code> tags write <kbd>Advertisement</kbd></p>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">2.</h4>
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Click Submit on the bottom of the page</p>
            </a>
            </div>

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
                <textarea id="answer" style="font-size:15px; resize: none; height: 400px; width: 100%; font-family: Consolas,monaco,monospace; background-color: #F9F9F9; color: #6F6F6F;">
<h1>Advertisement</h1>
<h2>This is Heading 2</h2>
<h3>This is Heading 3</h3>
<h4>This is Heading 4</h4>
<h5>This is Heading 5</h5>
<h6>This is Heading 6</h6>
<p>This is Paragraph Text</p>
<blockquote>
  <p>This is in a qoute</p>
  <small>Person <cite>Source Title</cite></small>
</blockquote></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Ad starts here-->
        <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- LRN Ad -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:100px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-9273905782779277"
     data-ad-slot="9421350343"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
        <!-- ends here -->
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <textarea id="html" style="font-size:15px; resize: none; height: 600px; width: 100%; font-family: Consolas,monaco,monospace; background-color: #6F6F6F; color: #F9F9F9;">
<h1>This is Heading 1</h1>
<h2>This is Heading 2</h2>
<h3>This is Heading 3</h3>
<h4>This is Heading 4</h4>
<h5>This is Heading 5</h5>
<h6>This is Heading 6</h6>
<p>This is Paragraph Text</p>
<blockquote>
  <p>This is in a qoute</p>
  <small>Person <cite>Source Title</cite></small>
</blockquote></textarea>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <br />
            <a onclick="ShowResult()" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Submit</a>
            <!-- Ad starts here-->
        <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- LRN Ad -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:100px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-9273905782779277"
     data-ad-slot="9421350343"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
        <!-- ends here -->

            <hr>
            <br/>
            <p>Copyleft ;-) Maksim Tonyushkin 2015</p>
        </div>

        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Textareas have no value attribute. You need to use innerHTML